# Why does invoking program by full path name give different result?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, time

`time ls` prints:

```
main  main.c

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

`/usr/bin/time ls` prints:

```
main  main.c
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2468maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+108minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Since `which time` prints `/usr/bin/time` I expected both outputs to be the same.

Why is the output different when invoking `time` by the full path name?

Comment: Do `type -a time`. Also `man time` versus `help time`

Comment: That gives `time is a shell keyword` `time is /usr/bin/time`

Comment: Two different implementations: one built into the shell, one living on the filesystem.